# How can I learn latest stable minor version of an Android support dependency?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, android-support-library

For example I want to use latest stable minor version ofcom.android.support:appcompat-v7 version 26. But I don't know where to get that information. Is it 26.86.76 or 26.2.65 or something else?

[image: com.android.support:appcompat-v7]

Comment: the way is not recommended for some reason, but you can use `:26.+`, and it will take the highest available version AFAIK

Comment: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: https://mvnrepository.com/

Search `com.android.support` and the first result is appcompat-v7. After entering it, click the `Google` tab and you can see all versions and their minor versions.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7?repo=google

Answer (score 1):

By hovering the mouse over the wanted dependency, and then by pressing alt+enter you get to see the latest dependency :)

Comment: That points to major updates as well and OP asked for minor only. Either way, support lib itself is deprecated and superseded by androidX.

Comment: @Pawel , By pointing to only one library, you can only update one. Also can check on "Google's Maven Repository" for a specific one.

Answer (score 1):

It needs a little more understanding.
 

When we add these dependencies and hit `build` button, at first it actually search for `repository site` where it will look for these repos. That may come from 'project level' gradle file where we add repository inside of buildscript or allprojects. Have you ever notice the site's link? Like - `maven.google.com / fabric.io`. These are the main repository hub for those dependency's where all repos exist. 
 
Now, come to the main point. If you hit http://maven.google.com it will reach you at https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html. Then you can look for your repos. 
If you want to find the latest support dependencies, at first type CTRL+F to find mother repo (like `support`). Then click `+` to navigate your child repos. You will get all the repos name from the beginning of google repositories serially.